# Google checkout sandbox: How to enforce an order to be pending for testing?

Tags: google-checkout

How can I configure a test order to be pending? I want to cancel pending orders but I have no idea how to test it since I cant enforce an order to be pending. Or can I? If yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

In the Merchant Center, make sure you do not automatically charge the buyer's credit card (under Settings -> Integration). The order will then be in the CHARGEABLE state and you can cancel it.

Below are the states for a Google Checkout order and related XML API commands:

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_Basic_HTML_Order_States.html

http://code.google.com/apis/checkout/developer/Google_Checkout_XML_API_Financial_Commands.html